# $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(1+e^{x})^2}dx$ by contour integration

Tags: improper-integrals, contour-integration

How would one compute the following integral using a ***contour*** in the complex plane? I know how to perform this integral by other means such as differentiation under the integration and series expansion.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(1+e^{x})^2}dx$$

One may try the full circle with a slit along the x-axis. However, it is hard to argue for the vanishing of the integral on the left semicircle at infinity.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to believe that this integral is tractable using contour integration? The integrand has poles at each $z = (2k + 1)i, k \in \mathbf{Z}$, so you won't be able to encompass all the poles in a single large contour.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn: A contour does not have to encompass all the poles in order to succeed in evaluate an integral. There are many examples of such contour integrals.

Comment: If it helps, the residue at $z=i\pi$ (point at which denominator becomes $0$ and having chosen $\arg z\in(0,2\pi)$) of $\oint\frac{\ln z\text dz}{(1+e^z)^2}$ is $2+\pi^2-2\pi i\ln\pi$.

Comment: **Hint:** $$(1+e^x)=0\Rightarrow x=\pi i.$$

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF.: What is the contour to solve the original integral?

Comment: @anonymous: What is your contour to solve the original integral?

Comment: @Hans any contour that includes $z=i\pi$ and avoids the branch cut due to $\ln z$. Though I am not entirely sure you'll be able to solve the integral using conventional contours.

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF.: You can certainly arbitrarily construct a contour to wrap around a pole, but to what end? The question is to solve *this* particular integral.